# table not appending dynamically in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, addition

I have made the function that helps me dynamically insert the new tr by just clicking one button, but when I reload the div with the help jquery and again hit the add new tr button it not appending.
I try to find the issue and I see the `tr#row_{num}` count is not resetting and starting from the last count.
for example -
If I appended `3` `tr` and reload the div and then, again when I click `button` for new tr adding it starting from `4` and not working/appending.

I used the `table empty();` function but it also not working.
Please help me with how I fix this issue -?

```js
$(document).on("click", "button#add_row", function() {
  var table = $("#myTable");
  var count_table_tbody_tr = $("#myTable tbody tr").length;
  var row_id = count_table_tbody_tr + 1;
  
  var html = '<tr id="row_' + row_id + '">';
  html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control ui-form-input firstname" autocomplete="off"></td>' + '<td> <input type="text" class="form-control ui-form-input lastname" autocomplete="off"></td><td></td></tr>';
  
  if (count_table_tbody_tr >= 1) {
    $("table#myTable tbody tr:first").before(html);
  } else {
    $("table#myTable tbody").html(html);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable" style="overflow-y: auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">First Name</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Last Name</th>
      <th style="width: 5%;">
        <button type="button" id="add_row" class="btn btn-default">Add ROW</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row_1">
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control ui-form-input firstname" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control ui-form-input lastname" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My JsFddle for live working is here [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/twt2shiv/trn3fgz4/9/)

Comment: This sounds like an event delegation issue due to your description of 'when I reload the div with the help jquery and again hit the add new tr button it not appending', however your example code doesn't show that logic.

Comment: Also note that you should look to remove the generated `id` attributes as it's an anti-pattern, and the last `if` condition check to determine if you use `before()` or `html()` can be completely replaced with `append()`

Comment: add code how you reload the table

Comment: ` $("div#div_id").load('tablePage.php');`

Comment: How I reset the `id`

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified to this

Note I moved the ID to to tbody

```js
$(function() {
  const $table = $("#myTable");
  const $row = $("#row_1");
  $("#add_row").on("click", function() {
    $table.append(
      $row
        .clone()
        .attr("id",`row_${$table.find("tr").length+1}`)
    )
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" style="overflow-y: auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">First Name</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Last Name</th>
      <th style="width: 5%;">
        <button type="button" id="add_row" class="btn btn-default">Add ROW</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr id="row_1">
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control ui-form-input firstname" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control ui-form-input lastname" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If the table is dynamic, you need

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click","#add_row", function() {
    const $table = $("#myTable");
    const $row = $("#row_1");
    $table.append(
      $row
        .clone()
        .attr("id",`row_${$table.find("tr").length+1}`)
    )
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" style="overflow-y: auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">First Name</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Last Name</th>
      <th style="width: 5%;">
        <button type="button" id="add_row" class="btn btn-default">Add ROW</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr id="row_1">
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control ui-form-input firstname" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control ui-form-input lastname" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```